# Android ASR multi locutors

Tags: android, ios, speech-recognition

I'm looking for an Automatic Speech Recognition solution for Android that can handle many locutors at the same time. I need a solution that can understand who is speaking what.

For example, if I have two users in front of my app, and if they are speaking at the same time, I need to know who said "YES" and who said "NO". My grammar is very simple, if it helps...

I've already tested both Android Recognizer Intent and implemented SpeechRecognizer, so I can already recognize the words, but I cannot associate them to specific locutors.

By the way, If you know this kind of solution for other platforms such as iOS or web-based app, I'll take it as well :).

Thank you.